# Enable talkd on ubuntu 11.04 server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to enable the talkd on an ubuntu server (11.04).

In my inetd.conf, I put:

```
#:BSD: Shell, login, exec and talk are BSD protocols.
talk        dgram   udp wait    root    /usr/sbin/in.talkd  in.talkd
ntalk       dgram   udp wait    root    /usr/sbin/in.ntalkd in.ntalkd
```

then restarted inetd, but still no talk server running.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: This has been a loooong standing issue. The Ubuntu community does not seem interested in supporting talk and personally I feel the tools should be removed from apt-get. Sad because I do this on every ubuntu server I run and then an hour of google searching I get depressed and attempt to install an IRC server. Here is the official bug report (which is now dead and won't fix) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ytalk/+bug/553736

Answer (score 2):

Those processes will not get spawned until someone connects to the talkd service.

Comment: Firing up talk just seems to complain about not talk daemon available. So I don't think it's firing up.  I can't believe it's this difficult to get talk up and running, AFAIR this was a basic linux/unix service :-/ - Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the talkd package (`apt-get install talkd` or your preferred equivalent package management tool)?

All the details in ined.conf do is tell the multi-service daemon to use the program if installed.

Comment: Yeah, double checked, it said it's already installed and up to date.